# Play dailymotion video on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, video, webview

Iam trying to play dailymotion video inside my android application's webview,the video's tumbnail is displayed but when i click the play button nothing happen ,i used :

```
String videoHtml = "<iframe frameborder='0'  src='http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/video_id'></iframe>
content.loadData(videoHtml, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

I remarked one thing is that when i open dailymotion's video in my browser and when i click the play button,the video begin to play in the default android media player!!

Comment: Try with the dailymotion´s sdk https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-android

Comment: Thank you very much @alexudave, :) ,i need one last thing is how to show progess dialog or a Toast after click on play botton?